# Button selects id

Tags: jquery, button, hyperlink

So I have these buttons and I want them to show a section with same id.

```
<aside>
    <button type="button" id="N">16-50mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="J">25-75mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="M">30-50mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="G">50-120mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="K">50-100mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="A">75-200mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="C">75-200mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="F">75-150mm</button>                  
</aside>

<section id="N">
    <figure>
        <a href="A1.html"><img src="Images/000-001.jpg" alt="Image1 A1"></a>
        <br>
        <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>

<section id="J">
    <figure>
        <a href="A1.html"><img src="Images/000-001.jpg" alt="Image2 A1"></a>
        <br>
        <figcaption>Name2</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

I saw somewhere people use data-id or data-attribute to show specific id. Can I make something like `<button type="button" data-id="N">16-50mm</button>` and it should show a `<section id="N">`. I appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: `ID` mustt be unique in a page. Make the second one css `class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen you cannot have duplicate `id` attributes in a single `document`. A better approach is to use `data` attributes. Try this:

```js
$('aside button').click(function() {
  $('section').hide().filter('#' + $(this).data('id')).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
  <button type="button" data-id="N">16-50mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="J">25-75mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="M">30-50mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="G">50-120mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="K">50-100mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="A">75-200mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="C">75-200mm</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="F">75-150mm</button>
</aside>

<section id="N">
  <figure>
    <a href="A1.html">
      <img src="Images/000-001.jpg" alt="Image1 A1">
    </a>
    <br>
    <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>

<section id="J">
  <figure>
    <a href="A1.html">
      <img src="Images/000-001.jpg" alt="Image2 A1">
    </a>
    <br>
    <figcaption>Name2</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/umud54dk/)

Comment: Oh man, you're my savior! That's exactly what I was looking for. I knew it is simple, but I haven't managed how to do this. Flawless, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ID` of the `section`s to class. Then use the following to get started.

```js
$('aside button').click(function(event){
  $('section.' + this.id).addClass('hide')
      .siblings('section').removeClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
    <button type="button" id="N">16-50mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="J">25-75mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="M">30-50mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="G">50-120mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="K">50-100mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="A">75-200mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="C">75-200mm</button>
    <button type="button" id="F">75-150mm</button>                  
</aside>

<section class="N hide">
    <figure>
        <a href="A1.html"><img src="Images/000-001.jpg" alt="Image1 A1"></a>
        <br>
        <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>

<section class="J hide">
    <figure>
        <a href="A1.html"><img src="Images/000-001.jpg" alt="Image2 A1"></a>
        <br>
        <figcaption>Name2</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you want a button to show section by button click event, you can't use same "id" on button and section. Maybe clarify your question so i can help you.

Comment: I think my question is quite clear. I appreciate your feedback, but @RoryMcCrossan answered it for me.